# Convergence in $L^p(B_r(0)) \implies$ convergence in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I'm trying to understand a certain proof and the author prove that $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2(B_r(0)), \forall r>0$ and he conclude that $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Initially I just think: "Oh, this is trivial". But now I'm not sure if that's really true, because to prove it I should be able to trade in the limits order, which in general needs some pretty strong hypotheses that aren't present in this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see how this relates to swapping the order of limits...? That's not really what this is about. You just need to look at $\int_{R^n} |f_n|^2$ and come up with an argument as to why it's small.

Comment: Also, is it the case that each $f_n$ actually belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, right?

Comment: If I trade the limits order: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |f_n|^2 dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |f_n|^2 \chi_{B_r} dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{B_r} |f_n|^2 dx =  \lim_{r\to \infty} \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{B_r} |f_n|^2 dx=0$, where $\chi$ is the indicator function.

Comment: You are very right and the conclusion in the proof is false without further assumptions.

Comment: A counterexample would be given by $f_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}1_{[-n;n]}$. In every ball you can just use dominated convergence (or explicitely compute) that the $L^2(B_r)$ norm goes to zero. On the other hand, $\Vert f_n \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} =1 $, so surely $f_n$ does not converge to the zero function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Another example is to take $f_n(x) = f(x-n\vec v)$, where $\vec v$ is a fixed vector and $f$ is a non-trivial function with bounded support.

Comment: I see now. But yes as others have pointed out, it cannot be correct as stated.

Comment: I think the limit interchange argument refers to $\|f_n\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^N)}=\lim_{R\to\infty} \|f_n\|_{L^2(B_R)}$, but one cannot interchange the limits for $R$ and for $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2(B_r(0)), \forall r>0$ does not even guarantee boundedness in $\mathbb L^2$ of $\left(f_n\right)$: mass can escape at infinity.

To get a concrete counter-example, take $f_n(t)=1$ if $n\leqslant t\leqslant 2n$ and $0$ otherwise. In this way, $\left\lVert f_n\right\rVert_{L^2(B_r(0))}=0$ for $n>r$ but $\left\lVert f_n\right\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=\sqrt{n}$.